# Fail to setup anaconda cluster on bare metal

Tags: anaconda, anaconda-cluster

My providers.yaml file

```
bare_metal:
cloud_provider: none
private_key: ~/.ssh/my-private-key
```

profile.yaml file

```
name: my_baremetal_profile
machines:
compute:
  - ip:port
head:
  - ip:port
node_id: bare_metal
node_type: bare_metal
num_nodes: 1
provider: bare_metal
```

user: user

then I start the cluster

```
acluster create xx --profile my_baremetal_profile
```

aborted with salt installing error

but ssh succeeded (aka. acluster ssh works)

but installing of salt failed with

```
FabricException: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: ip:port), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode
[ip:port] out: sudo password:
Fatal error: One or more hosts failed while executing task 'parallel_sudo'

Underlying exception:
Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: ip:port), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode
```

Aborting.

realized the FAQ here http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-cluster/faq

I have retried several times

======== Update ===================================================

reason of the above error is lack of passwordless sudo, after having fixed this. I still can not install notebook with command

```
acluster install notebook
```

got the following error:

```
FabricException: One or more hosts failed while executing task 'parallel_sudo'

Underlying exception:
sudo() received nonzero return code 2 while executing!

Requested: /opt/anaconda/envs/salt/bin/salt -G "roles:ipython.notebook" state.sls ipython.notebook.status test=True --timeout=60 --out=yaml --state_output=mixed
Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  /bin/bash -c  "/opt/anaconda/envs/salt/bin/salt -G \"roles:ipython.notebook\" state.sls ipython.notebook.status test=True --timeout=60 --out=yaml --state_output=mixed"

============================================================================================== Standard output ==============================================================================================

No minions matched the target. No command was sent, no jid was assigned.
{}
ERROR: No return received

=============================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you presumably forgot to set up a passwordless ssh connection and a passwordless sudo. Generate an ssh key on your management box with ssh-keygen and add itthe public part of the key to the authorized_keys file of the cluster nodes. As for sudo you will have to edit the sudo file of the nodes. Both of these requirements are written in one or the other of the anaconda cluster documentations.

Comment: thanks for the response. The passwordless ssh is not the private-public key given in my providers file ?

Comment: in the configuration file you tell anaconda-cluster which public key it should present to the remote box. Before running anaconda_cluster chec k whether you can enter the remote box with "ssh boxname" without entering a password. If you can't, anaconda cluster will not be able to work either.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I can ssh to the box using either ssh or acluster ssh

Comment: you are right I need a passwordless sudo addition to a passwordless ssh.